# What could be said about $U,V$ if $UN = VN$ for some $N \unlhd G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $N \unlhd G$ and let $U, V$ be two subgroups, if $UN = VN$, is it possible that $U \ne V$ if i) $U$ and $V$ are not contained in $N$, and ii) if $U\cap N = V\cap N = 1$.

Of course, if $U, V \le N$ then this is clear, as then $UN = N, VN = N$. So just choose two different subgroups of $N$, but I am asking for the other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $G:=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ choose $N:=\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$ it is normal in $G$. Choose $U:=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$ and $V:=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$. Then :

$$UN=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}=G $$

$$VN=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}=G $$

And $U\cap N=\{(0,0)\}=V\cap N$, but $U\neq V$.